90s British indie movie set in house in woods
This is what I remember:

I watched it on VHS in the 90s. I think it was probably released in the mid-90s.
A group of young Brits, maybe college students, go to a house in the woods for a weekend.
A woman wants to lose her virginity and is trying to decide on a partner. There is a competition between two guys. One guy really likes her. The other guy doesn't. I think one is black and one is white.
One of them either vanishes or is murdered.
The final shot is of wind blowing leaves in the woods.

The film was creepy, but not a horror movie. Does this ring a bell with anyone? Google isn't helping.

Thank you for writing a sensible, well fleshed-out ID question. One question... is it a British production likely? or is it Brits in the US? Oh, never mind, it's in the title. :P

Found it. It's a 1994 movie, available on Netflix Instant (of course, because it's a low-rated B movie), originally called "Loaded" and now called "Bloody Weekend":
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110374/
I got some of the details mixed up in my mind.

Don't forget to approve the answer (by clicking on the check mark next to it) to resolve it.
